# Replacing variable name with literal value in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm not quite sure how to phrase this question, so let me illustrate with an example.

Let's say you have a Pandas dataframe called `store_df` with a column called `STORE_NUMBER`. There are two ways to access a given column in a Pandas dataframe:

`store_df['STORE_NUMBER']`

and

`store_df.STORE_NUMBER`

Now let's say that you have a variable called `column_name` which contains the name of a column in `store_df` as a string. If you run

`store_df[column_name]`

All is well. But if you try to run

`store_df.column_name`

Python throws an `AttributeError` because it is looking for a literal column named "column_name" which doesn't exist in our hypothetical dataframe.

My question is: Is there a way to look up columns dynamically using second syntax (dot notation)? Not so much because there is anything wrong with the first syntax (list notation), but because I am curious if there is some advanced feature of Python that allows users to replace variable names with their value *as another variable* (in this case a state variable of the dataframe). I know there is the `exec` function but I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution. I tried

`store_df.{column_name}`

but received a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Yes, you want `getattr`, But you really should just use the first syntax (which is pandas best-practice anyway)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks! I will probably continue to use the first syntax, but I was just curious if it was possible using the second syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would `getattr(df, 'column_name_as_str')` be the kind of thing you're looking for, perhaps?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am looking for! Thank you! I did not know about the `getattr` function.